# MS Access Date Format and Compare yields wrong result

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

```
SELECT Format('06-12-2018','dd-MM-yyyy') > Format('31-07-2018','dd-MM-yyyy')
```

why i am getting output as '0' meaning false, while running this query on ms access ?

Comment: `Format()` returns a string so you are performing a string comparison & the first character `'0'` is not greater than `'3'`.  Compare date *types* via `cdate()` or `#06-12-2018#` (in your localized format)

Comment: @AlexK: There are no _localised formats_ for the #..# syntax. In VBA, the syntax is `#mm/dd/yyyy#`, ADO it is `#yyyy/mm/dd#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dd-mm-yyyy is your local format, use *DateValue*:

```
SELECT DateValue('06-12-2018') > DateValue('31-07-2018')
```

or, if the values are hardcoded, though this makes little sense, simply:

```
SELECT #2018/12/06# > #2018/07/31#
```

Comment: Datevalue also working .. but i want to format the date before comparing the dates. so i have used.. SELECT cdate(Format('06-12-2018','dd-MM-yyyy')) > cdate(Format('31-07-2018','dd-MM-yyyy'))

Comment: But that makes no sense. Date values have _no format_, so you are casting the string first to a date value for Format to read it, then format it to a string, which CDate then converts to a date value using your Windows locale.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT cdate(#06-12-2018#) > cdate(#31-07-2018#)
```

Comment: The format & cdate are unnecessary, ## already denotes a date literal, your going from date to string then back to the same date.

Comment: SELECT cdate(Format('06-12-2018','dd-MM-yyyy')) > cdate(Format('31-07-2018','dd-MM-yyyy'))  - this one working

Answer (score 0):

for datediff i think you need below type function
example

```
SELECT DateDiff("yyyy", #13/01/1998#, #09/05/2017#);
```